# Journey of a process from compilation to execution

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, os-kernel

I am reading operating system, and after reading some topics (Processes, Main Memory management) I got somewhat confused. I have knowledge about certain things but I am not able to combine and visualize them. Let's take an example - I have a simple programme as follow:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int add(int a,int b){
  return a+b;
}

int main(){
  int a=1,b=2;
  int c=add(a,b);
  cout<<c<<endl;
}
```

I want to know how this program will be loaded into the main memory and how will be getting the computation done.
I have certain points which I want to incorporate in the overall process.

1. At what stage and where will I be getting the 4 sections of memory .( Text, Data, Stack and Heap).
2. At what stage will the process be getting its PCB(Process Control Block.) Does PCB contains the 4 sections of process?
3. When and where is the role of CPU?
4. Address binding.
5. Loading
6. Linking.
7. Logical and physical address space.
8. Paging


   Please explain how the process will be executed including the above steps and other steps which take place in general.
   P.S. Please explain by assuming some memory addresses.

Comment: That sounds like a lot to ask for from a single answer.  We're looking for questions that can be answered in a few paragraphs. You have 8 different bullet points you are requiring people to address.  That seems like too much -- can you make your question more focused, e.g., to focus on a single one of those 8?  Also it is helpful to tell us what research you've done and what your current understanding is, and identify some specific aspect you're unclear on.  If you haven't done much research yet, you should do that before asking.